# Linking arrays according to common values

Tags: laravel

I have some array like

`0: [id: '1',department: 'xyz',date: '10-10-2019',time: '12:50']`

`1: [id: '1',department: 'xyz',date: '11-10-2019',time: '10:30']`

`2: [id: '2',department: 'abc',date: '09-09-2019',time: '09:50']`

`3: [id: '2',department: 'abc',date: '07-07-2019',time: '03:20']`

I want them to be merged according to the `id` and `department`

so the `0` and `1` array will be merged together and the output should be something like

`0:[id: '1',department: 'xyz',[[date: '10-10-2019',time: '12:50'],[date: '11-10-2019',time: '10:30']]]`

and the `2` and `3` array will be merged together and the output should be something like

`1:[id: '2',department: 'abc',[[date: '09-09-2019',time: '09:50'],[date: '07-07-2019',time: '03:20']]]`

how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 $input = [
0 =>['id' => '1','department' => 'xyz','date' => '10-10-2019','time' => '12:50'],
1 => ['id' => '1','department' => 'xyz','date' => '11-10-2019','time' => '10:30'],
2 => ['id' =>  '2','department' => 'abc','date' => '09-09-2019','time' => '09:50'],
3 =>['id' => '2','department' => 'abc','date' => '07-07-2019','time' => '03:20']];
$output = [];
$id_array = [];
foreach ($input as $values) 
{
  $id_array [] = $values['id'];
}
$unique_id_array = array_unique($id_array);
foreach($input as $key => $in)
{
  if(array_key_exists($key,$unique_id_array))
  {
    $output[] = [
            'department' => $in['department'],
            'id' => $in['id']
            ];
  }
}
foreach($input as $in)
{
foreach($output as $key => $out)
    {
      if($out['id'] == $in['id'] && $out['department'] == $in['department'])
      {
          $output[$key]['date_time'][] = ['date' =>$in['date'],'time' => $in['time']];
      }

    }
}
print_r($output);die();
```

The output is going to be

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [department] => xyz
        [id] => 1
        [date_time] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 10-10-2019
                        [time] => 12:50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 11-10-2019
                        [time] => 10:30
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [department] => abc
        [id] => 2
        [date_time] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 09-09-2019
                        [time] => 09:50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 07-07-2019
                        [time] => 03:20
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: No it does not returns output like you said

Comment: now how can I access each day and time according to the id and department?

Comment: use `foreach` loop on `$output` and based on `id` and `department` you can select date and time..

Comment: `foreach($output as $out)
{
    if($out['id'] == '1' && $out['department'] == 'xyz')
    {
        foreach($out['date_time'] as $date_time)
        {
        echo $date_time['date'];echo $date_time['time'];
        }
    }}`

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think this will works fine,and it's easy and best way to achieve your output.
i tried many codes in my system with data given by you,just try this
i hope this will work for you as well.

```
<?php 
    $inputArr =   [0 =>['id' => '1','department' => 'xyz','date' => '10-10-2019','time' => '12:50'],1 => ['id' => '1','department' => 'xyz','date' => '11-10-2019','time' => '10:30'],2 => ['id' =>  '2','department' => 'abc','date' => '09-09-2019','time' => '09:50'],3 =>['id' => '2','department' => 'abc','date' => '07-07-2019','time' => '03:20']];
    print_r($inputArr);
    $second_copy = $inputArr;
    foreach ($inputArr as $key => $single) 
    {
        $goalArr[$single['id']] = getRow($single['id'],$single['department'],$second_copy);
    }
    function getRow($id,$department,$second_copy)
    {
        $returnArr['id'] = $id;
        $returnArr['department'] = $department;
        foreach ($second_copy as $key => $single)
        {
            if($id == $single['id'] && $department == $single['department'])
            {
                $returnArr['date'][] = $single['date'];
                $returnArr['time'][] = $single['time'];
            }
        }
        return $returnArr;
    }
    echo "<br>Output is: <br>";
    print_r($goalArr);
?>
```